# error when deploying Java WS in Jboss 6.3.0 EAP

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I am migrating an application with Java WS from Jboss 5.1.0 to Jboss 6.3.0 EAP. It works fine with Jboss 5.1.0 but I am getting error while deploying the same in Jboss 6.3.0 EAP.

```
14:42:10,887 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deploy
ment.unit."my-app.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."dtm-banking.
war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "dtm-banking.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-a
s-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-ms
c-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.F
inal-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:118)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:137
)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:69)
        at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-a
s-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy371.visitLabel(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.createWrapperClass(WrapperClassGenerator.java:213)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.generate(WrapperClassGenerator.java:122)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.generatedWrapperBeanClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:6
83)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.getExtraClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:653)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBea
n.java:484)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:704)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBe
an.java:550)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java
:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitLabel(org.objectweb.asm.Label)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:85)
        ... 28 more
```

I understand Jboss 6.3.0 EAP uses CXF implementation for webservice, but I am looking for simple Java WS to use the standard Java EE environment.

tried the following in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="webservices" />
</exclude-subsystems>
```

this got rid of the exception at deployment time but I get a Classcast exception when invoking the wsdl for the service

http://localhost:8080/myapp/myservice?wsdl

JBWEB000235: Allocate exception for servlet MyWebService: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.webservice.endpoint.DataService cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is bundling `asm.jar` in your deployment.
Try remove it and add this to your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
       <dependencies>
            ...
            <module name="asm.asm" />
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

See more: https://developer.jboss.org/message/823745

Comment: where i can find "jboss-deployment-structure.xml"

Comment: @Dinesh-SriLanka `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is a deployment descriptor that you can add in your deployment like `jboss-web.xml`. See: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Answer (score 2):

[The answer](https://developer.jboss.org/message/823745) that fixed things for me was:

> I had the same problem. Adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml only
>   work for WAR files. If I depolyed the WAR inside an EAR I got the
>   error back.   So I added
>
> ```
>   <global-modules>
>     <module name="asm.asm" slot="main"/>
>   </global-modules>
> ```
>
> to the current jboss configuration, ie standalone-full.xml The it
>   work fine for me.

So if anyone stumbles upon this question, give it a try.

Comment: It's a bit old, but someone may still need it. In jboss-deployment-structure.xml you can also specify dependencies for sub-deployments of an EAR, such as this:
`<sub-deployment name="YourWebModule.war">
 <dependencies>
  <module name="asm.asm" />
 </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>`
In this way it works even if the WAR is inside an EAR.

Answer (score 0):

Rifer this page too.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/690353

> The above Error is thrown when for given class particular method not
>   found. Hence user is packaging asm jar in their application and class
>   "org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter" which contains in a jar does not have
>   method "public void visitLabel(org.objectweb.asm.Label);" hence
>   getting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException".